Capturing event from LWC to Aura using Light DOM
While trying using an Aura as parent and LWC as child, also adding the Shadow DOM as light I am unable to retrieve event information from a input-field.
Here is the example:
Consider Subject as a Standard field from Case Object.
aura cmp: parentAuraCmp.cmp
<aura:component controller="myController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global" >

 <div>
  <c:childCmpLWC/>
 </div>
</aura:component>

e.g.: childCmpLWC.html
    <template lwc:render-mode="light">
          <div>    
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Subject" name="Subject" onchange={handleChange}</lightning-input-field>
         </div>
</template>

childCmpLWC.js
export default class childCmpLWC extends LightningElement {
    static renderMode = "light";

    handleChange(event) {
            const field = event?.target?.dataset?.name;
            console.log('Field Name ' + field);
    
            const element2 = this.querySelector('[data-id="teste"]').value; //tried fetching using query selector but no success!
            console.log('Element2 ' + element2);
            
            const field3 = event.target?.dataset?.id;
            console.log('Test event.target ' + JSON.stringify(event.target));
            console.log('Test event.detail ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail));
            console.log('Test event.target.fieldname ' + event.detail.fieldName);       
            console.log('Test event.target.name ' + event.target.name); 
    
            console.log(field3);
            console.log('Test 1 ' + event.target.value);
            console.log('Test 2 ' + this.getAttribute('name'));       
            console.log('Test 4 ' + event.currentTarget.fieldName);
            console.log('Test 5 ' + event.target?.dataset?.id);
            console.log('Test 6 ' + event.target?.id);
            console.log('Test 6 ' + event.currentTarget?.dataset?.id);
            console.log('Test 7 ' + event.currentTarget?.id);
    }
}

*Note: not all elements are included in the input field such as data-id etc, resulting some of these items return blank.
For some reason (security mostly I'd say), when used an aura component to encapsulate the lwc, the event becomes empty. I have checked on the documentation and no mention of this limitation has been said by Salesforce.
Any thoughts?
